# Tkinter Frames - Classes

Tags: python, tkinter

So I'm using tkinter to make a GUI and at the moment I have several different frames. The way I programmed it is by just using one massive class but everywhere I look online (like here - https://pythonprogramming.net/change-show-new-frame-tkinter/), people are using a new class for every single "page". Is what I am doing wrong/not efficient or is it fine?

Unfortunately I cannot show my code as it's for a CA but the below is similar:

```
class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
         tk.Frame.__init(self)
         self.PageOne()

    def PageOne(self):
         coding stuff

    def PageTwo(self):
         pass
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is probably fine. I say "probably" because it depends on many factors which you haven't explained in your question.

The tutorial you referenced came from a [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7557028/7432) that was explicitly addressing how to switch between two frames. It's not necessarily a recommended way to code, it's simply one of many ways.

That being said, if you have distinct pages then you might find it easier to manage your code if each page was a self-contained object. Doing so gives each page its own namespace, so you don't have to worry that one page is accidentally modifying the data that belongs to some other page. Plus, for larger projects it allows you to implement each page in a separate file so you don't end up with one huge file full of code.

Since not all GUIs are oriented around the concept of pages, this technique isn't a one-size-fits-all solution. It's OK to make each page a class, it's also OK to create each page via a function. The choice depends on many variables, such as your comfort with working with classes, the size of your project, the type of UI you're creating, and so on.